# Sum ActiveRecord Relationship (Model + Model = Array?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm trying to sum two Active Model Relationship and order it by `created_at`.
The sum of dogs and cats make an Array. So I try to sort this array by `created_at` with `.sort_by( &:created_at )` but I get this strange error:

```
dogs = current_user.dogs
cats = current_user.cats
total = (dogs + cats).sort_by( &:created_at )

comparison of ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone with nil failed
```

There is another best way to sum two active record relationship and order it by created_at ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are `dogs` and `cats` ActiveRecord models? Do all of them have a `created_at` value?

Comment: Yes they have all created_at column. After hours, I solve it:

It works with:
dogs = Dog.where(user_id: current_user.id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your results has a `created_at` of `nil` it seems like, which is why you're getting that error. You can do the following to filter `nil` results

```
dogs = current_user.dogs.where.not(created_at: nil)
cats = current_user.cats.where.not(created_at: nil)
sorted_results = (dogs + cats).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

If you want to see which record(s) have `created_at` as `nil` do

```
nil_created_at_dogs = current_user.dogs.where(created_at: nil)
nil_created_at_cats = current_user.cats.where(created_at: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

If use .where, all works properly.

```
dogs = Dog.where(user_id: current_user.id)
cats = Cat.where(user_id: current_user.id)
total = (dogs + cats).sort_by( &:created_at )
```

I don't know why, but this is the way.